# What are the pros and cons of Milgard vs Jeld-Wen windows?

Tags: windows

I am replacing old window. The new window will be 69 1/2 inches wide and 59 1/2 inches tall.

I am thinking vinyl, two-vent slider (three equal sizes).

Home Depot suggests **Jeld Wen** ($500) for vinyl. A contractor quoted me **Milgard** (not sure of the price since it includes labor).

Is there any pros/cons to one brand or the other?

Comment: I've never heard of either of those.  What country are you in?

Comment: USA, California

Comment: I have Jeld wen double hung vinyl I don't like them they are hard to lock and the glass is cracking in the extreme cold we are having jeld wen doesn't want to do anything about it the windows are two years old

Answer (score 2):

I've got Milgard in my house and have been very pleased.  There was one window that after about 8 months became difficult to open.  I called up their service and they sent a guy to my house the next day and it was fixed all for free.  Their windows come with a lifetime warranty, though as I'm writing this I'm not sure if it is for the original owner or if it follows in a sale.  The double pane helped tremendously with noise reduction too.

Answer (score 2):

From what I heard, Milgard is higher up in the food chain then JeldWen. If they were cars, JeldWen would be Ford, and Milgard would be Benz. Also, they both have different lines of products with varying costs/features. So top-of-the line JeldWen window might be comparable in price/features to a mid-range Milgard. (In the case of JeldWen, their lines are actually different companies that JeldWen bought up over the years, so they can be a lot different quality-wise).